# Why do global and block scoped variables return different values of i?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/es6/compare-scopes-of-the-var-and-let-keywords

```
var printNumTwo;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (i === 2) {
    printNumTwo = function() {
      return i;
    };
  }
}
console.log(printNumTwo());
```

This prints 3 to the console.

```
let printNumTwo;
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (i === 2) {
    printNumTwo = function() {
      return i;
    };
  }
  console.log(i);
}
console.log(printNumTwo());
//console.log(i);
```

This prints 2 to the console. I've also added console.log(i); to debug and check the value of i throughout the loop, and it ends at i == 2. Does the loop exit when i == 2? I thought i would iterate to 3 and then exit when the condition i < 3 was false, which is when i == 3.

Why does i end at 3 in the first example and 2 in the second example?

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, where you are using the var keyword to declare the variable i, the loop runs three iterations with i being 0, 1, and 2. When i is 2, the condition i === 2 is true, and the function printNumTwo is assigned a closure that captures the value of i at that moment, which is 2. However, the var keyword has function scope, not block scope. It means that the variable i is shared across all iterations of the loop. After the loop finishes, the value of i is 3 because that's when the loop condition i < 3 becomes false and the loop exits. When you call printNumTwo(), it returns the current value of i, which is 3.

In the second example, where you are using the let keyword to declare the variable i, the loop also runs three iterations with i being 0, 1, and 2. However, let has block scope, which means a new i variable is created in each iteration of the loop. When i is 2, the condition i === 2 is true, and the function printNumTwo is assigned a closure that captures the value of the i variable in that particular iteration, which is 2. Since i is declared with let, the i inside the function is not affected by the changes in the loop iterations. When you call printNumTwo(), it returns the captured value, which is 2.

So, the difference between the two examples lies in the scope of the i variable. In the first example, i is shared across all iterations and is modified until it becomes 3 when the loop exits. In the second example, each iteration has its own separate i variable with a different scope, and the captured value of i in the function remains 2.

Comment: Does closure mean storing a function in a variable? Is function scope the same as global scope? I think the article referred to the first example as being globally scoped.

Comment: In the second example, does i still iterate to 3 and then exits the loop? I'm guessing the difference here is that in the second example, a new variable was created when i iterated to 3.

Comment: @Zaku Closure does involve storing a function in a variable, but it's more about capturing and maintaining access to the variables from the lexical scope (the scope where the function was defined) even when the function is executed outside that scope.

Comment: @Zaku So, the first example uses closure (capturing the variable i from the lexical scope) as well, but due to the difference in scoping behavior of var, it results in the final value being 3 when calling printNumTwo(), which might not be what was expected.